# Can't get Flask WTF to validate input properly

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to get Flask to check if my input is an integer and my form.validate_on_submit(): function is not working - the page just breaks when I type something in the field that is not an integer and gives me 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'

My main.py code is as follows:

```
from wtforms import IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from perfect_numbers import classify, listInRange

num = 1

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'DontTellAnyone'

class PerfectForm(Form):
    inputNumber = IntegerField('input a number', validators=[InputRequired(message='Please input an integer')])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = PerfectForm()
    Classify = classify(form.inputNumber.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        num = request.form['inputNumber']
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, num=num, classify=Classify)
    return render_template('index.html', num=1, form=form, classify=Classify)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're running this line `Classify = classify(form.inputNumber.data)` before actually filling out and validating the form. So move this line to somewhere after validating the form.